# App crashing immediately on start up after upgrading to iOS12

Tags: crash-reports, xcode10, ios12

My application is working fine on iOS 11.0. But when I am run on iOS 12.0 they crashing immediately on startup. My application is on Objective-C and MRC.

1. **Running fine in simulator but crashes in the device.**
2. **No main or didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is called yet.**
3. **Tried re-installing the application. Tried "Eare All Content and Settings" but it does not work.**
4. **Enabled zombie objects but even that did not help(no logs recorded).**

I also try to symbolicated the crash report but not find any solution from crash report.

I have attached my crash report here. 
[Crash Report](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4q1bljtdn98xzvo/eBook%20%2002-10-18%2C%207-27%20PM.crash?dl=0)

Comment: Post the relevant portion of the symbolicated crash log as text in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. The app is crashing just because of using an Old version of the Crittercism SDK. Upgrade to the latest version to support iOS 12.0.